# WPF datagrid - how to set checkbox in template column without binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, checkbox, datagrid

I have a datagrid, which is populated programatically by data retrieved from a webservice. The last column of the datagrid contains checkboxes, which allow to show each rows value on a map. The column is created with a template column like this:

```cs
DataGridTemplateColumn column = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
column.Header = "Show on map";
DataTemplate dt = new DataTemplate();
FrameworkElementFactory checkBoxFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(CheckBox));
checkBoxFactory.AddHandler(CheckBox.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(CheckBoxClicked), true);
dt.VisualTree = checkBoxFactory;
column.CellTemplate = dt;
DataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
```

If the users clicks on one of the checkboxes, the `CheckBoxClicked` method is invoked and displays the corresponding row values as an icon on the map (as already mentioned). This works very well. However, the user may close the window containing the datagrid, whereas the map stays on the screen, together with the displayed icons.

Now, when the user reopens the window with the datagrid, I'd like to preselect the checkbox, according to the already showing icons. Since the checkboxes do not have a binding, I'm unable to match the icons to them.
How can this be done? Is there a way to programatically preselect them? Or is there still a way to create a binding?

Comment: Please, please, please use XAML to set up your UI.

Comment: I've not done this for a while, but there should be an `IsChecked` property on each checkbox that you could set, similar to doing it WinForms style.  Otherwise, I recommend you use XAML to set up your UI and use a binding the easy way.

Comment: Well, thanks. But the content is highly dynamic and can't be set up with XAML.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I've found the solution. Hosch250s comment lead me on the right track (how can I upvote the comment?). The answer can be found here: [binding in code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742863(v=vs.100).aspx).

The easiest way set the checkbox state programmatically is to create this binding:

```
Binding binding = new Binding("IsChecked");
binding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
binding.Source = this;
checkBoxFactory.SetBinding(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty, binding);
```

And implement the property in the current context:

```
public bool IsChecked {
    get {
        return doWhateverToFindOutIfChecked();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first approach (see my answer with method binding) was simple and strait forward. However, one can not really determine, for which row the binding is called. I've changed the soluntion as followed:

Instead of a DataGridTemplateColumn I'm using a DataGridCheckBoxColumn, now. My data is dynamically stored in rows and bound to the ItemsSource property, using a ListCollectionView. The boolean values, required for the checkbox columns are dynamically inserted into the row values. My datagrid is read only and the selection unit is cell. Settings these properties, I can us the MouseUp event to detect a mouse click on a cell. Inside the handler method, I'll check if the click belonged to a checkbox cell. If so, I change the corresponding boolean value in the row values and call Items.refresh().